# Firebase Functions: What scheduling algorithm is used when retrying events? (exponential backoff, etc)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When Firebase Function events are retried, what replay algorithm is used? Or how often can I expect events to be retried?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions does not offer a guaranteed behavior on this.  The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#semantics_of_retry) merely states:

> When you enable retries on a background function, Cloud Functions will retry a failed function invocation until it completes successfully, or the retry window (by default, 7 days) expires.

And that's all you're given.  I would take this to mean that the system is free to adjust the retry frequency as it sees fit, based on internal configuration current conditions.